# Too many factor levels to display in Regression Tree in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and still figuring out the basics.

I have a fairly large data set where some factors have many categories.  How do I prevent R from including the labels in the tree image?  The result is attached and is illegible.  I'm using `rpart.plot`

[image]

Unfortunately, I may not reduce the number of categories.  Otherwise, I would have.